# Can I run old versions of (now incompatible) apps on MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, mac-appstore

A bunch of apps require an M1 chip when you try to download from the App Store.

Specifically, I'm asking about Classplus. https://apps.apple.com/in/app/classplus/id1324522260

 I'm pretty sure it's not an iOS app that's using the M1 chip; its first update was on 3 June 2020. My MacOS version is Big Sur 11.2

Is there a way to download an older version that doesn't require the M1 chip?

Comment: This is a [common situation where apps that take advantage of something new just don’t support older OS or chips or systems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380672/5472). Can you edit in the bunch of apps (or better one app) in case we can answer this definitively?

Comment: @bmike I made the edit

Comment: That's an iOS app, they only run on M1 Macs (and on iOS devices). There is no general macOS version available.

Comment: The  url you give actually says "Designed for iPad" so it never ran on Intel macOS

Comment: This is now a fabulous question. I’ll edit or answer tomorrow based on catalyst framework why this may be very hard or “unpossible” in the near term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple currently recommends that developers make Universal Binaries for BOTH CPU types. Are you sure that apps only support the M1 CPU and don't work on Intel? Can you give us some examples?

They may be advertising that they will work natively on M1, but I would still expect all Mac App Store apps to support Intel CPUs.

EDIT: The app is an iOS app, which previously would only run on iPads or iPhones. The new M1 Macs can also run these apps. It's unlikely that there was ever an Intel version of this app (as there are no Intel i-devices).

Comment: Currently you'll basically only find apps that either support ARM **and** x86 or **only** x86. However, Apple has done a great job to make x86 only apps work on M1 chips, with its translation layer Rosetta 2.

Comment: Now we know. This is about running iPad and iOS apps that are catalyst based. This has turned into a fabulous question now that is edited with some details

Answer (score 2):

The app you linked is in fact an iOS app, and as such requires an M1 chip. Its most recent update was March 2021.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to download an older version that doesn't require the M1 chip?

This assumes an older version exists and the developer hasn't crippled it in some way.  Someone might have an old x86-64 version of the installer somewhere but it might require a serial number, need to "phone home" for activation, or something to make it work.  If the developer revokes permission for the app to run then getting it to run will not be easy.

As other answers point out Apple will certainly do what they can to assure people with Intel based Macs can run anything in the App Store for years to come but it's up to the developer to want to create an Intel compatible app and make it available.

It's possible that someone, at some point, will make an M1 Mac emulator for Intel Macs to allow the running of newer apps on older Macs.  The M1 is based off ARM and there are 64 bit ARM emulators available now, with QEMU as one example, that could be updated and expanded to run macOS for M1 on macOS for Intel.  I believe this to be nearly inevitable, just not likely to happen tomorrow.